# PHP Design Patterns for mapping many MySQL tables

Tags: php, mysql, oop, design-patterns

Ok, so I thought about implementing the Active Record Design Pattern for mapping a class over some tables in my MySQL database.

The thing is I want a generic class that will shuffle through my tables, doing basic CRUD transactions, based on what properties (fields from my db) are selected.

So I have methods for CRUD, which I want to select based on the properties passed to the object, properties which I access using __get and __set methods.

I thought about using an array, having it's keys as table prefixes and it's values another array containing the list of properties from each table.

But I think this is to complicated, cause I`ll have to shuffle thru a whole array to select the specified table.

Can you point me to some design tips I could use?
Thanks!

Comment: I think your class is trying to do too much (encapsulting several tables sounds quite inflexible). Search around for data mapper, table gateway and dao.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a pre-built library, like Doctrine, Propel or PHPActiveRecord that can generate your class files from the existing DB Schema. Also have a look at http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/index.html for some ideas about the fundamental patterns used in Object Relational Mapping, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem to solve is "handle tables" then that is the way to implement.

What are the commands you wish to perform? insert record, delete record?

Create a entity **Table** that represents a table, value object **Column** that represents a column, a **Record** that represents a table row, and fine grain as much as needed.

Then you are ready to use every single table.

Usage should be as simple as:

```
<?php 
$usersTable = new Table($connection, 'users');

// sample search
$userRow = new Record('user');
$usersTable->find(array('id' => 1), $userRow);

// sample insert
$row = new Record('users', array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'jose'));
$result = $usersTable->insert($row);
```

But would only recommend that is that is really the problem, otherwise you should represent business entities as such: Users, Order, etc..